# How to convert virtual address to physical address from user space? Three different methods gave different results in Linux kernel 4x version

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, x86-64, tlb, page-tables

First of all, I’m sorry for so long question.

I do some simulation modeling task and I need to translate user space virtual address into kernel space physical addresses. I used three different method and got three different results.
Could you please give me an advice what method is correct and why they are provide different results?

> CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz
>
> OS: Linux Fedora release 22 (Twenty Two)
>
> Kernel: 4.4.4-200.fc22.x86_64

I read many different sources but confused by many old information related to before 2.6 kernel version or not to 64bit Intel architecture.

> Method 1.

As I understand, I have only one method to convert the address (VA->PA) from the user space. This could be done by using /proc/self/pagemap. This file provide PFN (Page Frame Number) by virtual page number as offset in the file.

```
virtualPageNumber = virtualAddress / systemPageSize;
lseek(pageMapFile, virtualPageNumber * sizeof(void *), SEEK_SET);
size_t bytesRead = read(pageMapFile, &physicalAddressPFN, sizeof(void *));
```

and `physicalAddressPFN +  (virtualAddress - virtualPageNumber)` will be the physical address itself.

This approach provide me following example address conversion:

```
Virtual Address : PGD  : PUD  : PMD  : PTE  :offset:  pagemap value :physical address:  PGD address   :  PUD address   :  PMD address   : PTE address
         15920f0:     0:     0:     a:   192:    f0:8180000000138622:       1386220f0:       137090000:       137090000:       138490000:   138622000
```

`PGD:PUD:PMD:PTE` are extracted from virtual address by using bitfileds as described here https://lwn.net/Articles/117749/

“pagemap value” is the 8 bytes extracted from `/proc/self/pagemap`

Also, I’m interested in addresses of the page table layers (each of four-level page table). I looked to http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/mm/dump_pagetables.c#L376 that, as I understand, used to produce kernel page table in `/sys/kernel/debug/kernel_page_tables`

```
cat /sys/kernel/debug/kernel_page_tables
Example output from my system:
---[ User Space ]---
0x0000000000000000-0xffff800000000000    16777088T                               pgd
---[ Kernel Space ]---
0xffff800000000000-0xffff880000000000           8T                               pgd
---[ Low Kernel Mapping ]---
0xffff880000000000-0xffff880000099000         612K     RW                 GLB NX pte
0xffff880000099000-0xffff88000009a000           4K     ro                 GLB NX pte
0xffff88000009a000-0xffff88000009b000           4K     ro                 GLB x  pte
0xffff88000009b000-0xffff880000200000        1428K     RW                 GLB NX pte
etc
```

This approach used in reverse direction (calculating PGD/PUD/PMD/PTE offsets from physical address). Results of this represented in fileds `“PGD address:PUD address:PMD address:PTE address”` above.

For example:

```
addrPTE = physicalAddress - vaOffset;
addrPMD = addrPTE - (vaIdxPTE * PTE_LEVEL_MULT);
addrPUD = addrPMD - (vaIdxPMD * PMD_LEVEL_MULT);
addrPGD = addrPUD - (vaIdxPUD * PUD_LEVEL_MULT);
```

where vaIdxPUD is index of the PUD from virtual address and `PMD_LEVEL_MULT = PTRS_PER_PTE * PTE_LEVEL_MULT` as described in http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/mm/dump_pagetables.c#L101

All calculation above are done from the user space.

The next thing is how to check correctness of these addresses manipulation.

> Method 2.

I implemented simple LKM (Linux Kernel Module) with addresses translation. This LKM interact with user space program by /proc files. I used `/proc/my_input` to write the virtual address that I would like to translate and read translated information from `/proc/my_output`.

I can’t use this method in my general task and I implemented it just to check correctness of the address translation.

In the LKM I used

```
unsigned long addrPA = virt_to_phys((void*)addrVA);
```

and this method gave me

```
[259084.890129]
                Given virtual address 0x15920f0
[259084.890131] Physical address provided by virt_to_phys() 0x7800015920f0
```

This is different from the address from method 1 that provided `PA 0x1386220f0` as exposed above.

> Method 3.

I tried to walk on page table and find all four-level page table address.

```
   struct page *page = NULL;
    struct mm_struct *mm = current->mm;

    pgd = pgd_offset(mm, addr);
    if (pgd_none(*pgd) || pgd_bad(*pgd)) {
        goto out;
    }
    printk(KERN_NOTICE "Valid pgd %p", pgd);
    *pgdVar = (unsigned long) pgd;

    pud = pud_offset(pgd, addr);
    if (pud_none(*pud) || pud_bad(*pud)) {
        goto out;
    }
    printk(KERN_NOTICE "Valid pud %p", pud);
    *pudVar = (unsigned long) pud;
etc...
```

This method gave me following

```
                Given virtual address 0x15920f0
[259084.890132] Valid pgd ffff880038ac0000
[259084.890134] Valid pud ffff880147039000
[259084.890134] Valid pmd ffff88018a2f6050
[259084.890135] page frame struct is @ ffffea0004e18880 pte ffff88003876ec90
```

The PTE address is far from PA addresses found by previous methods.

> So, these three methods provide different results.
>
> Method 1: VA: 0x15920f0 -> PA: 0x1386220f0
>
> Method 2: VA: 0x15920f0 -> PA: 0x7800015920f0
>
> Method 3: VA: 0x15920f0 -> PA: 0xffff88003876ec90

What is the right method to get VA->PA translation from user space and find page tables address?

How to check the correctness of the method (can be at kernel level)?

Thank you

Sergey

> **Update 1.**

I collect event traces from large HPC MPI applications to simulate different addresses behavior at HW level. I need to know physical addresses to understand how many different addresses used at particular time by application at particular MPI rank. I can't use kernel space level for VA->PA translation because no HPC cluster administrator allow me root privileges on real machine (need Top500 class machines for investigations).

This is quite big task and I didn't want bother readers by this redundant explanation.

Comment: The reality is that it is unlikely anyone is going to read and try to understand such a long post. Suggest you attempt to condense your question to improve your chances of it being answered.

Comment: Why do you think you need the physical address? What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Physical addresses make little sense in user space. Page maps change as stuff goes in and out of swap. At most you can get info like "virtual address X corresponded to physical address Y at some recent point in time, but not necessarily now".

Comment: The TLB is a cache for page-table entries.  You seem to be using it as a term to describe page-tables, which is incorrect.  Other than that, +1 for some interesting reading.  I didn't know Linux exposed enough info to user-space for a process to get physical addresses.  I agree with the other comments though: this seems unlikely to be useful, except maybe as part of some kind of exploit against Linux.  (If you can overwrite something in kernel memory somehow, and you need correct physical addresses to get privilege escalation instead of a crash?)

Comment: This is incorrect: ```physicalAddressPFN +  (virtualAddress - virtualPageNumber)``` you need to scale by systemPageSize

Comment: Also when running ```virt_to_phys``` within the kernel module, are you sure it's the user space virtual address that's being converted?

Comment: Finally, given it's been several years curious to know what approach you found that worked?